# Future and Try duality

Tags: scala

I was looking at this lecture, https://class.coursera.org/reactive-002/lecture/135 at 2:15.

The lecturer talks about the duality of `Future` and `Try` in Scala. For his demonstration he changes the type:

```
(Try[T] => Unit) => Unit
```

into:

```
Unit => (Unit => Try[T])
```

and he says something about duality(which I'm not familiar with).

How does he jump from one step to the other?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it requires an enrollment in a Coursera course to answer.

Comment: It would be useful if you could give more detail about the point being made.  At the very least, it would help if you explain what the types being worked on *are*, and what it means for the lecturer to have "changed the type" (has some actual function been changed?).

Comment: This could be turned into a decent question if it was self-contained. Not sure if including a (very brief) transcript of that section of the video would violate Coursera's copyrights.

Comment: I have asked a similar question on another forum: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20117/in-what-sense-are-scalas-tryt-and-futuret-dual

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note: I am not an expert in Category Theory. If you want a *precise* explanation what Duality means in Category Theory, you should ask a mathematician.

The concept of [duality in Category Theory](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(category_theory)) can be kind-of thought as "opposite", but it is a special kind of opposite, one that preserves structure. For example, the dual of a directed graph is the graph which has all the arrows reversed. So, the graph is in some sense the same (it has the same edges and vertices), but in some sense the opposite.

Another example is De Morgan's Law: `∧` and `∨` are duals, so if we "dualize" `¬(A ∨ B)`, we end up with `¬A` being the dual of `A`, `¬B` the dual of `B`, and `∨` the dual of `∧`, so the end result is `¬A ∧ ¬B` … and we didn't have to memorize anything, it was all just purely thoughtless mindless mechanical substitution.

Now, for Function Types, the idea is similar to the one for graphs: the dual type is just the type with all the arrows reversed. So, the dual of `(Try[T] ⇒ Unit) ⇒ Unit` is `(Try[T] ⇐ Unit) ⇐ Unit`, or, if we write the arrows "the right way" `Unit ⇒ (Unit ⇒ Try[T])`, which because of right-associativity of `⇒` is just `Unit ⇒ Unit ⇒ Try[T]`.

The reason why Duality is interesting, is that because of the fact that some structure is preserved and some things are opposites, we know a lot about the Dual just by looking at properties of the Original. Let's go back to the graph example: we know that the dual graph has the same number of edges and number of vertices, in fact, it has the same set of edges and the "mirrored" set of vertices. It has the same equivalent undirected graph. It has the same number of cycles. And so on. This means that some properties of the original get carried over to the dual, and some properties get reversed. So, if we have proved or computed some properties of the original, we get the corresponding proof for the dual for free.

Also, because some sort of structure is generally preserved between the two, libraries that rely only on the structure just work with the new type without having to do anything.

The most widely-known and widely-used examples of this is probably the [`IObserver`/`IObservable` interface pair in .NET, which was derived by mechanically dualizing `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerator`](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Brian-Beckman-and-Erik-Meijer-Inside-the-NET-Reactive-Framework-Rx), after Erik Meijer discovered that reactive/event-based programming is the dual of interactive programming and thus the Subject/Observer Design Pattern *should* be the dual of the Iterator Design Pattern. The most interesting thing that gets preserved by this dualization is the fact that `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerator` is a monad (an instance of the List Monad), and thus `IObserver`/`IObservable` is a monad as well (an instance of the Continuation Monad). Both C♯ and Visual Basic.NET have built-in language support for monads (LINQ Query Comprehensions), and this just works with `IObserver`/`IObservable`.

The *most* important thing, however, is that because of the structure-preservation reactive programming with events can be written in much the same way as interactive programming with iterators.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you! I have a follow up question: Wikipedia defines interactive programming as  `the procedure of writing parts of a program while it is already active`. How is the Iterator Design Pattern connected to that? As far as I know, when you are iterating over a collection, you're not changing the code of your program.

Comment: There is no connection. It's one of those cases where the same term is used to mean different things. The definition you find is about the programmer interacting with the program. What I mean is the program interacting with the environment. In other words: Interactive programming is the programming we have been doing since the beginning of programming, where *you* call the environment at a time of *your* choosing, whereas in reactive programming, the *environment* calls you at a time of *its* choosing. Note how we have again duality here? The *structure* of the sentence is preserved, but the …

Comment: … *subjects* and *objects* are reversed! Similarly, in interactive programming, there is a loop in *your* code, which *pulls* values from the iterator when *you* want, in reactive programming, there is an event loop in the *environment*, it *pushes* values to you when *it* wants.

Comment: @octavian: There's a nice explanation in the first few minutes of this video: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/E2E-Erik-Meijer-and-Wes-Dyer-Reactive-Framework-Rx-Under-the-Hood-1-of-2 Note the diagram for the call-flow in interactive and reactive programming. It's again the same diagram, but the arrows are reversed. In other words, the call-flow diagram for reactive programming is the dual of the diagram for interactive programming, which then gives the idea that reactive programming is the dual of interactive programming, which *then* gives the idea to mechanically dualize the …

Comment: … interfaces used for interactive programming, and the result is a beautifully simple interface for reactive programming that actually preserves a lot of the properties of the interfaces for interactive programming and thus is easy (or at least easier than some of the existing approaches) to learn and use.